# imitate strcpy function in c using char pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I am try to write a user defined function which will do exactly what `strcpy()` library function do. But although there is no error, my program crashes and not copying second string to first string. What's wrong with this code and how to fix it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){

    char *ch1="abcd";
    char *ch2="efgh";
    str_cpy(ch1,ch2);

}

str_cpy(char *c1,char *c2){

    int i=0;


    while(c1[i]!='\0'){

          i++;
    }
    printf("%c",*(c1+3));
    int k;
    for(k=0;k<=i;k++){

          *(c1+k)=*(c2+k);
    }

}
```

Comment: The destination `ch1` is read-only, because it is an unmodifiable string literal. There's also no point in initialising it, since it will be overwritten. You want `char ch1[5]` here.

Comment: comments flew over my head..simplified version please

Comment: I've removed the second comment, which was only a recommendation. `char *c1 = "stuff";` defines a pointer to an immutable string literal. `char c2[5];` defines a writable buffer for up to four characters plus null terminator. You'll have to understand that if you want to program in C; there is no simplified version.

Comment: @AL-zami My solution is the simplest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals are generally put into read only area, that's why the program crashed when you are writing into `c1`. The destination string needs to be an array or allocated buffer:

```
char c1[5];
str_cpy(c1, c2);
```

Also, in the function, it looks you are copying `c2` to `c1`, but you are counting the length of `c1`, you should count the length of `c2` instead:

```
// copy string c2 to c1
void str_cpy(char *c1, const char *c2){

    int i=0;
    while(c2[i]!='\0'){
      i++;
    }

    int k;
    for(k=0;k<=i;k++){
        *(c1+k)=*(c2+k);
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the const char for?

Comment: @AL-zami It is to annotate the function that the source string `c2` will be not changed in the function, only `c1` will be changed.

Comment: it works without the cons though .is it really necessary?what problem it might create if i don't use the const keyword?

Comment: @AL-zami It helps the user of your API to know that the effects and requirements of the arguments, it may also help the compiler to detect potential bugs and do certain optimization based on that.

Comment: if i have a larger string in ch1='abckABCK' , after copying it is only "efgh",the last four digits "ABCD" are lost.why is this happening?

Comment: @AL-zami That's because strings in C are null-terminated, and the null terminator in `c2` are copied into `c1`, which ends the string as "ABCD".

Comment: i see...k<=i causing the problem.should be k<i only...it copied the null character

Comment: yes, right, note the standard `strcpy` also does this, because copy means copy and overwrite, not replace ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Your program invokes undefined behavior because you are trying to write to a string literal.  String literals can be stored in read only memory, which is probably the case on your system, hence causing a crash.

Note that your string copying function can perform the copy in a single loop:

```
char *str_cpy(char *c1, const char *c2) {
    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
        c1[i] = c2[i];
        if (c1[i] == '\0')
            return c1;
    }
}
```

You can verify the behavior with a modified `main`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *str_cpy(char *c1, const char *c2) {
    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
        c1[i] = c2[i];
        if (c1[i] == '\0')
            return c1;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char buf[20];
    char *ch2 = "Hello world\n";
    printf("%s\n", str_cpy(buf, ch2));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible rework of your code, which doesn't have to pre-define buffer size (c1). You simply pass the buffer address. Also, please note that such buffer has to be freed once used (for example, if declared in local scope, not in `main()`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *str_cpy(char **c1, const char *c2) {
    int i, size = 0;
    for(i = 0; ; i++)
        if(c2[i] == '\0')break;
    size = i + 1;

    if(!(*c1 = realloc(*c1,size*sizeof(char))))
        return *c1;//or devise some more sophisticated error handling
    for (i = 0;; i++) {
        (*c1)[i] = c2[i];
        if (c2[i] == '\0')
            return *c1;
    }
}

int main(void){
    char *ch1 = malloc(1); //you're responsible for freeing it, once used 
    char *ch2 = "Hello, everybody in the neighborhood!";    
    printf("%s\n",str_cpy(&ch1,ch2));
    free(ch1);
    return 0;
}
```

Please, also note you don't need to `#include <string.h>`